# Parabolic water flow from hole in water bottle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

When the lid is not kept on and a hole is created about an inch or two from the bottom the water bottle, I observed that the water flows out the bottle in a parabolic manner. What is the reasoning behind this mechanism?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%2527s_law&ved=2ahUKEwjPuZaLpqvqAhWEfH0KHfprCqgQFjAYegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw146Dxlkjd8taTLOmsI1Vkx Torricelli Equation

Comment: If a narrow vertical slit is made in a cylindrical container or in a water dam, the envelope of parabolas is seen to form a perfect $45^{\circ}$ beautiful transparent water sheet right triangle.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the water spout as a stream of low friction sandy particles being pushed out. If the hole created is at an angle in a thick container, using standard parametric equations for uniform motion:

$$ x= u t, y= ut + \frac12 g t^2$$
Eliminating $t,$ a standing water trajectory has the form
$$y=x+ \frac{gx^2}{2u^2}$$

which is path taken by a single projectile fired at an angle for some initial velocity/component.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it as a stream of particles coming out from the hole
Now you can relate it with a particle having some initial velocity (water inside pushes water at the corner with a force)
You can apply the equation of motion to find the time period and height.

---

$H=\frac{1}{2} gt^2$,          h-height of hole from ground

Range=$ut$

---

So you see it will have a parabolic path similar to a projected particle when the particle is at its maximum height